# Sidekiq authentication default action (device)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, device, sidekiq

when using authentication on sidekiq monitor

```
authenticate :admin do
  mount Sidekiq::Web => '/admin/sidekiq'
end
```

the default action after auth fail is to redirect to the admin login path (using device), is it possible to change that action to use render_404 for example?